# How to reverse BLDC motor using programming arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, pwm, servo, robotics

I bought ESC from [**here**](http://www.rcbazaar.com/product.aspx?productid=2443) but it rotates motor in one direction only.

Is there any program which will control direction of rotation clockwise or anticlockwise with same wire configuration.

Comment: I don't know - that page won't load.  If the ESC has a direction input then you need to control that with an IO pin.  If no, then it's probably not possible.

Comment: R/C Hobby ESC's come in unidirectional (for aircraft) and bidirectional (for surface vehicles) versions.  If you have the latter and configure the throttle ranges correctly, part of the PWM range will be reverse.   But you may not be out of luck even with the former, as many ESC's are built in common ways around ATmega or SiLabs chips for which open source replacement firmwares have been published, and these typical have a bidirectional option.

Comment: If above link does not work it is the RS695 unit [**here**](http://www.rcbazaar.com/category.aspx?categoryid=47). With same leads, maybe no. If you use a DPDT relay (double pile changeover) to swap 2 leads it will usually reverse direction.

Comment: Manual [**here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4saiZvhGj-CUlhmX05MQkhKMm8/edit) - not helpful in this case, alas.

Comment: If you mean the FUFEI-12A, a web search shows several hits implying people have put the popular "simonk" firmware on that, and there are versions of that online which have been modified with reversing.  So the goal seems achievable, the question is if it would be more expedient to just buy a small car ESC.  I'd be very hesitant to use a relay, both given the currents involved and that the ESC may really, really dislike having the windings interchanged when it is even slightly active, so careful locking out will be required.